# Make a query that only shows rows that has no null values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a query statement that will only grab the rows that consist of no null values in its columns. But I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here is the query statement:

```
    $query = "SELECT scrap_wafers.lot, scrap_wafers.wafer_cell, scrap_wafers.flow, ".
"scrap_wafers.route, scrap_wafers.scrap_date, scrap_wafers.scrap_comment, ".
"scrap_type_names.scrap_tag_name, scrap_wafers.engineer, scrap_wafers.disposition_date, ".
"scrap_wafers.disposition_comment, scrap_wafers.location, scrap_wafers.serial_sw, scrap_wafers.operator ".
"FROM scrap_wafers ".
"LEFT JOIN scrap_type_names ON scrap_type_names.serial_stn = scrap_wafers.serial_stn ".
"$cstring ".
"GROUP BY scrap_wafers.serial_sw ".
"ORDER BY scrap_wafers.scrap_date DESC ".
"LIMIT $numrecs";
```

$criteria consists of:

```
$criteria = array();
if (!empty($lot)) {
 $lotarray = explode(',', $lot);
 $lot_criteria_str = "(";
 foreach ($lotarray as $lottmp) {
  $lot_criteria_str = $lot_criteria_str . "scrap_wafers.lot like '%$lottmp%' OR ";
 } 
 $lot_criteria_str = substr($lot_criteria_str,0,-3); 
 $lot_criteria_str = $lot_criteria_str . ")";
 $criteria[] = $lot_criteria_str;
 }
if (!empty($wafer_cell)) {
 $waferarray = explode(',', $wafer_cell);
 $wafer_criteria_str = "(";
 foreach ($waferarray as $wafertmp) {
  $wafer_criteria_str = $wafer_criteria_str . "scrap_wafers.wafer_cell like '%$wafertmp%' OR ";
 } 
 $wafer_criteria_str = substr($wafer_criteria_str,0,-3); 
 $wafer_criteria_str = $wafer_criteria_str . ")";
 $criteria[] = $wafer_criteria_str;
 } 
    if (!empty($serial_flow)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.serial_flow = '$serial_flow'";
    if (!empty($serial_route)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.serial_route = '$serial_route'"; 
    if (!empty($operator)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.operator = '$operator'";     
    if (!empty($serial_stn)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.serial_stn = '$scrap_tag_name'";               
    if (!empty($scrap_date)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.scrap_date = '$scrap_date'";   
    if (!empty($serial_step)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.serial_step = '$serial_step'";    
    if (!empty($location)) $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.location = '$location'";             
    if (!empty($completeness)) {
        if ($completeness == 'Default') { 
        // Do nothing
        }
        else if ($completeness == 'Incomplete') {
            $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.disposition_date = null AND scrap_wafers.engineer = null AND ".
            "scrap_wafers.disposition_comment = null AND scrap_wafers.location = null AND  ".
            "scrap_wafers.serial_stn = null";
        }
        else if ($completeness == 'Complete') {
            $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.disposition_date = not null AND scrap_wafers.engineer = not null AND ".
            "scrap_wafers.disposition_comment = not null AND scrap_wafers.location = not null AND  ".
            "scrap_wafers.serial_stn = not null";
        }
    }   
$cstring = "";
    if (count($criteria) > 0) {
        $cstring = "WHERE ".join(" AND ", $criteria);
    } else {
        $cstring = "WHERE 1=1 ";
    }
```

$completeness is where I'm trying to filter for either null values(incomplete) or no null values(complete).

Comment: Use "IS NULL" rather than "= NULL"

Comment: The tests for null/not null are `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`. You cannot use the equal sign for these tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html), not `= null`.

```
...

else if ($completeness == 'Incomplete') {
    $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.disposition_date IS NULL AND scrap_wafers.engineer IS NULL AND ".
    "scrap_wafers.disposition_comment IS NULL AND scrap_wafers.location IS NULL AND  ".
    "scrap_wafers.serial_stn IS NULL";
}
else if ($completeness == 'Complete') {
    $criteria[] = "scrap_wafers.disposition_date IS NOT NULL AND scrap_wafers.engineer IS NOT NULL AND ".
    "scrap_wafers.disposition_comment IS NOT NULL AND scrap_wafers.location IS NOT NULL AND  ".
    "scrap_wafers.serial_stn IS NOT NULL";
}

...
```

Comment: No worries. Feel free to accept if this answer solved your question. But, it should be pointed out that this has been answered 100 times on stackoverflow already, so search around more next time ;)

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you for the heads up, next time I'll make sure to search around more next time :)